# Python/Matplotlib - How to put text in the corner of equal aspect figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to put text in the right bottom corner of equal aspect figure.
I set the position relative to the figure by ax.transAxes, 
but I have to define the relative coordinate value manually depending on height scales of each figures.

What would be a good way to know axes height scale and the correct text position within the script?

```
 ax = plt.subplot(2,1,1)
 ax.plot([1,2,3],[1,2,3])
 ax.set_aspect('equal')
 ax.text(1,-0.15, 'text', transform=ax.transAxes, ha='right', fontsize=16)
 print ax.get_position().height

 ax = plt.subplot(2,1,2)
 ax.plot([10,20,30],[1,2,3])
 ax.set_aspect('equal')
 ax.text(1,-0.15, 'text', transform=ax.transAxes, ha='right', fontsize=16)
 print ax.get_position().height
```

[image]

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Use `annotate`.

In fact, I hardly ever use `text`. Even when I want to place things in data coordinates, I usually want to offset it by some fixed distance in points, which is much easier with `annotate`.

As a quick example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, subplot_kw=dict(aspect=1))

axes[0].plot(range(1, 4))
axes[1].plot(range(10, 40, 10), range(1, 4))

for ax in axes:
    ax.annotate('Test', xy=(1, 0), xycoords='axes fraction', fontsize=16,
                horizontalalignment='right', verticalalignment='bottom')
plt.show()
```

[image]

If you'd like it slightly offset from the corner, you can specify an offset through the `xytext` kwarg (and `textcoords` to control how the values of `xytext` are interpreted).  I'm also using the `ha` and `va` abbreviations for `horizontalalignment` and `verticalalignment` here:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, subplot_kw=dict(aspect=1))

axes[0].plot(range(1, 4))
axes[1].plot(range(10, 40, 10), range(1, 4))

for ax in axes:
    ax.annotate('Test', xy=(1, 0), xycoords='axes fraction', fontsize=16,
                xytext=(-5, 5), textcoords='offset points',
                ha='right', va='bottom')
plt.show()
```

[image]

If you're trying to place it below the axes, you can use the offset to place it a set distance below in points:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, subplot_kw=dict(aspect=1))

axes[0].plot(range(1, 4))
axes[1].plot(range(10, 40, 10), range(1, 4))

for ax in axes:
    ax.annotate('Test', xy=(1, 0), xycoords='axes fraction', fontsize=16,
                xytext=(0, -15), textcoords='offset points',
                ha='right', va='top')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Also have a look at the [Matplotlib annotation guide](http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_guide.html) for more information.